# how to distinguish whether the switch is clicked by manual operation or triggered by switchChange.bootstrapSwitch for bootstrap switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap Switch:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e,       state) {
  var  _this = e.target;
   if ($(_this).is(":focus") == false) return;
  _this.bootstrapSwitch('state',true); 

});
```

I try to use the code as below : `'if ($(_this).is(":focus") == false) return;'` to distinguish whether the switch is clicked by manual operation or triggered by `'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch'` event for  bootstrap switch, but it doesn't work.

so how to distinguish whether the switch is clicked by manual operation or triggered by `'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch'` event for  bootstrap switch?

Comment: create a variabele on the side to keep track?

Comment: add a class/atribute to the checkbox

Comment: I try to add an onclick event to the checkbox and change a class/attribute when the checkbox is clicked by manual operation,but it doesn't work .it seems that the onclick event is prevented by Bootstrap Switch .

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Why do you think you need to do this? What is the bigger picture/problem?

Comment: @RoToRa  there is at least one situation I encountered,for example : if I want to do something such as validating or giving alert messages for user to confirm the changing operation before making the switch change its state ,in this circumstance,it doesn't work,'cause it has triggered the  'switchChange' event  and the switch button has turned on or off,so no matter whether it shows a confirm dialog or not, the switch has changed its state.  'switchChange' is after-change event, so why not give us a before-change event to do something before the switch changes its state?